# Issue showing images on build and start with Vue and Electron

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder

I am building an app with vue and electron but the only way I it shows the image if I input the full path
`src="D:/electron-project/src/assets/logo.png"`

if I try `src="../assets/logo.png` then it builds the image as `file://D://img/logo.png` and does not load the image.

Tried reading all I could but could not find the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `src="@/assets/logo.png"` or `:src="require('@/assets/logo.png')"`

Comment: Thanks I had tried that but it was not working . Now it is.